# Efficient serverside batch deletion via Artifactory REST API

Tags: artifactory

I'm looking for an efficient way to remove a large set of artifacts, spread across various locations from Artifactory (by retrievable with a search query).

I've tried using the JFrog CLI 'rt del' command (along with an AQL file) to search and then remove results, and this works.   However, I am finding the removal rate is pretty slow for our instance -- around 1 artifact removal/sec.   I will need to remove several hundred thousand artifacts, and this will take way too long.   So I am looking for a batch removal mechanism which executes entirely serverside.

I noticed the Artifactory UI supports a 'search stash' feature where a search can be performed, then saved off and results can be acted upon (including deletion action).  Is this available via the REST API?   This seems like it would be a good match for this use-case.

Alternatively, is there a way to perform a search by creation date in the UI?  If so, I could presumably use the search stash feature and perform the removal on the search stash.

Last option I can think of is to write a custom plugin to do this work, but I am hoping there is an easier way as it seems like a semi-common case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting from search stash would delete the artfifacts from the stash results but won't delete from the artifactory(as per my understanding).

There is groovy plugin available that will clear your artifacts depending on few conditions(link below)

[Groovy Clean Up](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins.git)

I found Artifactory AQL quite helpful in searching and deleting artifacts.

Also I had written a custom clean up script that in turn used aql to delete the artifacts for repo regex match and also checks for the artifacts promotion status

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @error404 -- the cleanup plugin has addressed this issue -- the removal speed can be specified, and I am now seeing 20 deletes/second.  :-)

Comment: most welcome @Moosetracks@ Happy that the answer was helpful